# sqlite3 update conflict with django (Windows10) SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17))

Tags: django, sqlite

I am using Windows 10 and installed django When I navigate into the folder where the manage.py file is an run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get the following output

```
SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17))
```

I am using python 3.7.7 and the package for Sqlite installed is 3.31.1. Any ideas how to fix this?

Tried to downgrade to django 2.1.2 via pycharm but did not work.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: What happens when you run `python3 manage.py runserver`?

Comment: many thanks, if I enter that in the terminal in pycharm nothing happens. I just moves to the next line

Answer (score 0):

It looks like django is using an older version of SQLite. Assuming you are using django 2.2, it needs sqlite version >= 3.8.3.

To check which version of SQLite python is using :

```
$ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 12 2019, 16:23:13) 
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.27.2' #This should give you 3.31.1
```

To check which version of SQLite your system is using

```
C:\>sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.15.2 2013-01-09 11:53:05
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

If it's not the right version, consider installing the SQLite package from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_installation.htm)

**Steps to install SQLite on Windows**

1. Step 1 − Go to SQLite download page, and download precompiled
   binaries from Windows section.
2. Step 2 − Download sqlite-shell-win32-*.zip and
       sqlite-dll-win32-*.zip zipped files.
3. Step 3 − Create a folder C:>sqlite and unzip above two zipped files
       in this folder, which will give you sqlite3.def, sqlite3.dll and
       sqlite3.exe files.
4. Step 4 − Add C:>sqlite in your PATH environment variable and
       finally go to the command prompt and issue sqlite3 command, which
       should display the following result.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. The problem is that sqlite3.sqlite_version gives me 3.7.17 but if I check the installed package in pycharm is see 3.31....

So I do not understand why that is the case?

Comment: It looks like the system is using the `3.7.17` as the default instead of the pycharm package. What I would suggest you do is to set your path variable to point to the package in pycharm instead of  `3.7.17`. And upon running `sqlite3.sqlite_version` it should give you the latest version.

Comment: sorry, could you tell me how to do that? Unfortunately I do not know how to find path variable....

Comment: I updated sqlite3 within this virtual environment and still the same....

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I checked out the video but as I have installed sqlite only via python I do not really undertand that. Sorry, I am not able to solve it. I have deinstalled my anaconda and pycharm. I then installed all completely fresh. I then updated sqlite via conda in the environment. When I then check the sqlite version in my pycharm I get again 3.7.17

I am really confused....Where is this old version coming from? Where can I delete it?

Comment: If I type "C:\>sqlite3" in the command prompt it does not find anything...

Comment: Did you follow step.4 in setting your path in environment variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210467/discussion-between-azycrw4282-and-rolf12).

Comment: I did. I added to the environment variables "C:\Users\RR\anaconda3\pkgs\sqlite-3.31.1-he774522_0\Library\bin" 

same result